# python decorator for directory

Tags: python, scripting, decorator

I often find my self writing a python script which takes parameters:

`python my_script.py input_file output_file other_parameter_a other_parameter_b optional_parameter_c`

Now, I want the option to either run the script on a single file like what the above would do, or run it on every single file in a directory. I find myself writing a new script `my_script_run_on_directory.py` that looks up every file in a directory and then calls `my_script.py` So, I would have:

`python my_script_run_on_directory.py directory_input directory_output other_parameter_a other_parameter_b optional_parameter_c`

I need to do this often and I keep writing a new directory script for each `my_script`. Is there a better way to do this? I thought of using decorators but not sure what the best way to do this is.

I suppose what I want is something like

```
python general_run_on_directory_script.py my_script directory_input directory_output <and all other paremeters needed for my_script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for your question on what to use. In general, I'd say abstract the generic code away in a function that takes a specific function as an argument. Using a decorator is a rather clean way to do this. So in my opinion, yes it is a good solution.

Simple case (always expecting the same argument for your function):

```
import os

#Define decorator, takes the function to execute as an argument
def dir_or_file_decorator(func):
    def newFunc(path):
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            filenames = os.listdir(path)
            for filename in filenames:
                filepath = os.path.join(path,filename)
                func(filepath)
        else:
            func(path)
    return newFunc

#Define the function we want to decorate
@dir_or_file_decorator       
def print_file_name(filepath):
    print filepath  

#Run some tests
print 'Testing file'    
print_file_name(r'c:\testdir\testfile1.txt')
print 'Testing dir'
print_file_name(r'c:\testdir')

#The @decorator is just syntactic sugar. The code below shows what actually happens
def print_file_name2(filepath):
    print filepath

decorated_func = dir_or_file_decorator(print_file_name2)
print 'Testing file'    
decorated_func(r'c:\testdir\testfile1.txt')
print 'Testing dir'
decorated_func(r'c:\testdir')

#Output:
# Testing file
# c:\testdir\testfile1.txt
# Testing dir
# c:\testdir\testfile1.txt
# c:\testdir\testfile2.txt
```

More complicated cases:

Extra arguments in your functions:

```
import os

def dir_or_file_decorator(func):
    def newFunc(path, *args, **kwargs):
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            filenames = os.listdir(path)
            for filename in filenames:
                filepath = os.path.join(path,filename)
                func(filepath, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            func(path, *args, **kwargs)
    return newFunc

@dir_or_file_decorator       
def print_file_name_and_args(path, extra):
    print extra, path   

#We can use the parameter order in the function (our decorator assumes path is the first one)
print_file_name_and_args(r'c:\testdir', 'extra for test 1')
#Or we can just be safe and use named arguments (our decorator assumes the argument is named path)
print_file_name_and_args(extra='extra for test 1', path=r'c:\testdir')
#A combination of both is possible too (but I feel it's more complicated and hence more prone to error)
print_file_name_and_args(r'c:\testdir', extra='extra for test 1')

#Output (in all 3 cases):
# extra for test 1 c:\testdir\testfile1.txt
# extra for test 1 c:\testdir\testfile2.txt
```

Having to return values as well:

```
import os

def dir_or_file_decorator_with_results(concatenateResultFunc):
    def dir_or_file_decorator(func):
        def newFunc(path, *args, **kwargs):
            if os.path.isdir(path):
                results = []
                filenames = os.listdir(path)
                for filename in filenames:
                    filepath = os.path.join(path,filename)
                    results.append(func(filepath, *args, **kwargs))
                return concatenateResultFunc(results)
            else:
                return func(path, *args, **kwargs)
        return newFunc
    return dir_or_file_decorator

#Our function to concatenate the results in case of a directory
def concatenate_results(results):
    return ','.join(results)

#We pass the function used to concatenate the results in case of a directory when we apply to decorator
#What happens is that we create a new dir_or_file_decorator that uses the specified concatenateResultFunc
#That newly created decorator is then applied to our function
@dir_or_file_decorator_with_results(concatenate_results)
def get_file_name_and_args(extra, path):
    return extra + ' -> ' + path    

#Test again
print get_file_name_and_args(r'c:\testdir', 'extra for test 1')

#Output:
# c:\testdir\testfile1.txt -> extra for test 1,c:\testdir\testfile2.txt -> extra for test 1
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. So you think decorator is the right way to go? Where does the wrapper get the path variable that you have?

Comment: Sorry, weekend happened. I'll update my answer right away with a more in depth example. In short, the wrapper doesn't need to get the path variable, it returns a function that takes a path variable. This will be more clear in the updated example.